# Modern Latin for pixel

Tags: contemporary-latin

I want something concise that gives an immediate idea of what the word means like Bildpunkt in German. An academic friend has suggested pixellum, with a gloss like "elementum vel στοιχεῖον minimum
imaginis electronicae”. Can the Latin ST suggest a better or briefer alternative?

Comment: A personal friend of mine, Emeritus Professor James Diggle, suggests 'pixillum' rather than pixellum as being more Latin-looking. I would add an explanatory gloss like the above or perhaps minuta puncta electronicae imaginis.

Comment: A personal friend of mine, Emeritus Professor James Diggle, suggests 'pixillum' rather than pixellum as being more Latin-looking. I would add an explanatory gloss like the above or perhaps minuta puncta electronicae imaginis. Alternatively, the modern Greek εικονοστοιχείο could be used, sounding somewhat bar barbarous in Latin, viz. iconostoechīum.

Answer (score 4):

How about **abaculus** (mosaic tile)?

Comment: An excellent idea.

Comment: a good alternative to abaculus would be "tessera" (the Latin-borrowed Greek word for mosaic tile or other small square)